# How to fix only homepage loading on node application, other routes give 404

Tags: node.js, nginx, ubuntu-18.04

I'm using the server blocks feature of nginx to host my node app on a subdomain. But I am only able to access the homepage of the application. eg: subdomain.example.com works but subdomain.example.com/users gives 404

I followed the documentation on Digitalocean

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/staging.xxxxxxx.com/html/xxxxxxx/src;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name staging.xxxxxxxx.com www.staging.xxxxxxx.com;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    }
}
```

Comment: try to enable logs in your config file. it gives you more details.

```access_log /var/log/nginx/staging.xxxxxxxx.com.log main;
error_log /var/log/nginx/staging.xxxxxxxx.com.log;```

Comment: And post your main log: ```cat /var/log/nginx/error.log```

Comment: @metallic I did that and everything seems to work properly now... I guess omitting those custom error logs had effect in the server block. Thanks